# Silverlight or MVC 2 (or MVC 3?) for my business app?

Tags: silverlight, model-view-controller

Is Silverlight a good choice to use to develop an in-house app ERP business app?  Or would MVC be a better choice?

The app would have to include orders processing, pick lists, accounting, purchasing, reporting, etc.

Comment: You will never be able to replace a desktop application with MVC, neither 2 or 3, and that is because IE has a very buggy and slow JavaScript engine, which means AJAX just doesn't work there. So Silverlight is the way to go, there really is not much choice. If the dominant browser was Google Chrome, that would be different, but since that is not so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ask yourself (and perhaps your client) a couple of questions:

What are your users used to?

What are your users expecting?

If you are replacing a desktop application then Silverlight might be the better choice as it replicates more closely the desktop "experience".

If you are replacing a web site/intranet application then MVC might be the better choice.

Comment: This will be replacing a MS Access forms application.  I'm leaning more towards Silverlight, but I'm not sure if it's best suited for business applications.

Comment: @Scottie - I'm part of a team writing a business application in Silverlight, we think it is ideally suited to the task.

Answer (score 2):

The choice between the two will depend on your requirements and your client(s) expectations.

ASP.NET MVC may be perfectly suitable for you if your clients can accommodate the limitations of a web-based application.  AJAX and other techniques can be used to make a web-based app "feel" like a locally-installed application.

As it happens, I am writing an ERP system in Silverlight at the moment.  The target clients are accustomed to "fat-client" applications that are capable of opening multiple windows at a time.  They are generally non-technical and are amenable to installing the Silverlight runtime.  That and the need for fast, responsive UI drove the selection of Silverlight.

Comment: Thanks!  That makes me feel better knowing someone else has blazed this trail before!  If I may ask, are you using RIA and Entity Framework as well?

Comment: @Scottie: Using both RIA and EF.  Still in the UI prototyping stages at this point, should be moving on to getting RIA Services soon.  Check out StatLight for automated testing.